# error with RegistryValueKind

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a application and i'm getting an error message here:

```
regkey.SetValue(valuename, value, RegistryValueKind.String)
```

the error message is: 
'RegistryValueKind' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Someone any idea's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this on the top of your application: Imports Microsoft.Win32